# Heavenly sound system by grotesque creatures

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge, geography

> I am part of South America
>   [ ] geographically
>   [x] politically
>   [ ] culturally.
>
> I am
>   [ ] in the Bahamas
>   [x] older than that.
>
> I unscramble
>   [x] the suffering caused by an ending marriage
>   [x] a heavenly sound system by grotesque creatures
>   [ ] an adult clip recoded by an intelligence agency.

What am I? The answer is one word.

Comment: If you want, you could write `$\boxed{\times}$` to generate $\boxed{\times}$. Likewise, you could write `$\Box$` or `$\square$` to generate $\Box$. Just saying :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are  (edited at @MOehm's suggestion)

> Providencia

I am part of South America politically

> Geographically, the Caribbean islands are generally grouped as a part or subregion of North America, but politically, Providencia is part of Colombia

I am older than that

> Providencia started as a colony in 1629, the Bahamas in 1718.

I unscramble the suffering caused by an ending marriage

> "divorce pain" can be found anagrammed in Providencia

I unscramble a heavenly sound system by grotesque creatures

> "Divine Orc PA" found anagrammed in Providencia.

Bonus

> I [don't quite] unscramble an adult clip recoded by an intelligence agency yields
>  CIA prn video
>  found anagrammed in Providencia.

Comment: Well done. I think you should anagram just the name proper, i.e. the last word, to get exact unscramblings (and a one-off for the unchecked one.)

Comment: @MOehm edited per your suggestion.  thanks!

Comment: Nice solve. For the plural creatures there is also another anagram of your one.

Comment: NP! I think you can include both for the plural. (Top question as usual).

Comment: Nice work! For the second clue I was thinking of rot13[Arj Cebivqrapr] in the Bahamas, but this works as well.